# Java reenrantlock unlock throws java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, locking

The thread needs to acquire multiple locks before execution, so I put all locks to a list, and iteratively tryLock() them, if the tryLock() success, I add the acquired lock to a list called acquiredLocks, so when any lock'tryLock() fails, I can unlock the already acquired locks,
but when the rollback happens, it throws java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException by ReenrantLock because the lock was not held by the current thread. And I checked the acquiredLocks list, some locks in it indeed are acquired by another thread, but I called tryLock() before adding it to the acquiredLocks list.

```
private final List<Lock> locks = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
private final List<Lock> acquiredLocks = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();


/**
  * try to acquire all locks, if any lock is not acquired, roll back and release all already acquired 
  * locks
  */
private boolean tryAllLocks() {
        for (Lock lock : locks) {
            if (lock.tryLock()) {
                acquiredLocks.add(lock);
            } else {
                acquiredLocks.forEach(Lock::unlock);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}

 public PriceGenerationAggregate call() throws Exception {
        try {
            if (TenorConst.isSpotTenor(marketPriceCache.getTenor())) {
                this.priceGenerationAggregate = new SpotRootPriceGenerationAggregate(marketPriceCache, synchronizeForwardSpotPrice());
            } else {
                this.priceGenerationAggregate = new ForwardRootPriceGenerationAggregate(marketPriceCache);
            }

            for (GenerationProduct generationProduct : priceGenerationAggregate.getAllSubscribedPriceForPriceGeneration().getAllGenerationProducts()) {
                Lock lock = ProductLockCache.getLock(generationProduct.getCcyPair(), generationProduct.getTenor(), generationProduct.getVolume());
                locks.add(lock);
            }
            // try all the locks before the price generation
            while (!tryAllLocks()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            generatePrices();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            releaseAllLocks();
        }

        return priceGenerationAggregate;
    }
```

Comment: Is `tryAllLocks` invoked by multiple threads simultaneously? If so, you're sharing `acquiredLocks` between threads.

Comment: And if that isn't the problem, or is only part of the problem, then note I don't see you clearing `acquiredLocks` either.

Comment: acquiredLocks is a new instance for every thread, it's not shared

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting to clear the list of acquired locks after unlocking. After unlocking, they're no longer acquired, and other threads can lock them: as you mentioned, you saw locks from `acquiredLocks` being held by other threads.

Add a `acquiredLocks.clear();` statement after unlocking (this only works under the assumption that `acquiredLocks` has a new instance of a list for every thread).

```
private boolean tryAllLocks() {
    for (Lock lock : locks) {
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            acquiredLocks.add(lock);
        } else {
            acquiredLocks.forEach(Lock::unlock);
            acquiredLocks.clear(); // <-- added
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this is it, although the acquiredLocks is a new instance for every thread, the locks are added to acquiredLocks in every while loop, thanks. I'll try to fix it at the office tmr